# Sql*Plus ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

I installed Sql*PLUS on a cloud Oracle Linux Environment in order to access an remote database. I used the installation instructions provided as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488394/how-to-install-sql-plus-client-in-linux

My connection string is correct, but I get the error

`ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

I tried resolving this issue by attempting to looking at my `tnsnames.ora`, but it did not exist and the path connected to my `$ORACLE_HOME` did not have the subfolders "`/network/admin/`". In order to resolve this, I created both folders and created a `tnsnames.ora` file in the new `admin/` containing my connection string. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

The path to my new `tnsnames.ora` file being:
`/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`

For reference my connection string is structured the following way:

```
(DESCRIPTION=
     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= asdasdasd.com)(PORT=1524))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = AARCER1)
    )
  )
```

And my command I am putting into my terminal is: 
`sqlplus "userName/myPassword@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=asdasdasd.com)(PORT=1524))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=AARCER1)))"`

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: does `tnsping AARCER1` work? Or `sqlplus userName/myPassword@AARCER1`?

Comment: I think that it is a good habit to set TNS_ADMIN env variable in your profile and point it to your folder with tnsnames.ora. Especially helpful when using more than one client on one machine.

Answer (score 7):

When you use `sqlplus userName/myPassword@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=asdasdasd.com)(PORT=1524))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=AARCER1)))"` then you don't need any `tnsnames.ora` file.

Your entry in `tnsnames.ora` file should be like this:

```
AARCER1 = (DESCRIPTION=
     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= asdasdasd.com)(PORT=1524))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = AARCER1)
    )
  )
```

Then you can shorten your command to `sqlplus userName/myPassword@AARCER1` - that is the purpose of `tnsnames.ora`.

In order to use `tnsnames.ora` you must also have file `sqlnet.ora`.
There you need an entry like this:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)
```

However, default value is `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(tnsnames, ldap, ezconnect)`, so actually you can skip it.

Set environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to location of these files, i.e.

```
export TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the tnsnames.ora file by using the EZ Connect method.

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@asdasdasd.com:1524/<service name goes here>
```

You can get your service name by running lsnrctl status command.

Comment: I successfully tested my scripts using the above method. But when I transfer the scripts to another server, the connections fails (12154). Any idea where should I check?